# Angular bootstrap button click function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a simple form of my template. In form there is already a validation is added i just need to check when user click on button after all required field how is it possible ?

```
<section class="contact-area pb-80" style="margin-top:10%">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>Your Information</h2>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <p>Please provide the correct information we will contact you with your information.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                <img src="assets/img/1.png" alt="image">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter your name">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter your email">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your number (Whats app)">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="msg_subject" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" required placeholder="Enter your skype name">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my code I need to simply check when user clicks on `Send Message` But after all fields are filled as in form. Validation is working fine but the problem is how can I check the button?

I have created a simple function like this

```
submit(){
  console.log('submit');
}
```

I if add `(click)="submit()"` on the button so every time the user clicks it's calling the function. I want when all fields are filled then this function can work.

Comment: This is not an Angular form...? I’d investigate Angular Reactive Forms..

Comment: Yes its not simple bootstrap form but use in angular.

Comment: What you want is easy in a Reactive Form.

Answer (score 0):

Inner template:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <input ngModel name="name" type="text" required />
  <input ngModel name="email" type="email" required />
  <input ngModel name="phone-number" type="text" required />

  <button (click)="onSubmit(myForm)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Innner `.ts`:

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  console.log(form.invalid);
}
```

Be sure that you have imported `FormsModule` into your module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [..., FormsModule, ...],
  // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Important: `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` into your app-module and add it to the imports array.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [FormsModule],
})
```

Create a template variable in form element like `myForm` given below  and on button tag make use of property binding `[disabled]="!myForm.form.valid"`. Now Submit button will only work when each form element is filled.

Template file:

```
    <form #myForm="ngForm" method="POST" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm)">
  <div>
    <label>Name</label>        
    <input name="name" type="text" required ngModel/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" required ngModel/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Phone no</label>
    <input name="phone" type="number" required ngModel/>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
  <pre>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

You can find my code snippet on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pyuzjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)